# Delayed invalidation of something in multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, lock-free

Each thread of my program has its own log file. In my `SIGHUP` handler I want to notify those threads that when a new log message arrives, they need to reopen their log files.

I want a lock-free solution based purely on flags and counters. (I do have a thread-local context structure for another purpose, so I can add new fields there).

If there was just one logging thread, I would do:

```
static int need_reopen = 0;

void sighancont(int signo)
...
  case SIGHUP:
    need_reopen = 1;
    break;
...
}

void log(char *msg) {
    if (need_reopen) {
        need_reopen = 0;
        reopen_log();
    }
    ...
}
```

Of course, if there are multiple logging threads, a simple flag won't do. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
static volatile int reopen_counter = 0;

void sighancont(int signo)
...
  case SIGHUP:
    __sync_fetch_and_add(&reopen_counter, 1);
    break;
...
}

void log(struct ctx_st *ctx, char *msg) {
    int c = reopen_counter;
    if (ctx->reopen_counter != c) {
        ctx->reopen_counter = c;
        reopen_log();
    }
    ...
}
```

This way the logging threads are supposed to catch-up with the global counter. If the program receives SIGHUP multiple times, log files will be reopened only once.

I see the only way to break this - to send SIGHUP ~4 billion times.

Is there a better (but still simple) algorithm, e.g. with reference counting?

Comment: You have a data race in your code. You can't read and modify the same variable from multiple threads if the value is not atomic.

Comment: @SergeyA in sighancont() or in log() ? If you mean 2 concurren SIGHUPS, I can live with that

Comment: there is a synergy between them both :)

Comment: `reopen_counter = reopen_counter + 1;` is not thread-safe.

Comment: I don't modify the global counter in log()

Comment: @Naveen I can live with that too

Comment: @basin, but you read it there! And, if you can live with data race (why?), why are even asking this question?

Comment: @SergeyA `reopen_counter` may change between comparison and assignment, but that's not a disaster

Comment: @basin, it is not about being changed. It's about no guarantee whatsoever that one thread will see the modification done by another.

Comment: @SergeyA added atomic operations.

Comment: @SergeyA, you definitely can read and write from multiple threads. The result is less than well defined if you write from multiple threads, but this is not the case here.

Comment: @BitWhistler plain wrong. I mean, yes, you can - but results are unpredictable.

Comment: @SergeyA,
when thread A updates a value from 100 to 101, threads B,C,D,... can read 100 or 101. They can not read 300. You get this behavior with or without atomics. Nothing unpredictable here.
The purpose of atomics is to guarantee a single writer. We're not talking about a lock with data here. Only a single variable.

Comment: @BitWhistler, they can. This is what  you are not getting.

Comment: @SergeyA, you can run a simple test - some writer threads (or just one) continuously change an int's value between 100 and 101, and some reader threads continuously read it. See if they ever get anything other than 100 or 101. Your test would fail only with unaligned ints or if they're bigger than the native word size. You should really read the Intel docs on that, dude.

Comment: @BitWhistler, since when tests are any proove of undefined behavior? You are terribly misguided. Also, who said anything about Intel, *dude*?

Comment: @SergeyA, downvote all you like. I have better things to do than to argue with you.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is simple and efficient. This is kind of a seqlock.

A few notes, to clear possible confusion from comments:

1. There's no "atomic variable" but atomic instruction. std::atomic, and friends, are just syntactic sugar around atomic ops - you're perfectly ok  there.
2. The counter doesn't have to be volatile, but the accesses have to be. When you write `atomic_read(x)` you actually say `*(volatile int*)&x`.
   The volatile qualifier causes all accesses to the variable to be done from memory, while you don't necessarily need that.
   But, here as well, you're perfectly ok, since you read the variable into a local.
3. You can update the counter non-atomically if this is the one and only writer (don't forget to make it `atomic_write` if you remove the `volatile`). This would be a very small performance improvement.
4. The only cost here is in the log threads that have to pay for main memory access after the counter is updated. You should expect 200 cycles or so (x2 on other NUMA node)